# How to create an easy to add package?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, package

I've been gathering components from react websites that i've created, i would like to know if there is a way for me to create a package, which instead of copying the code over and over again, i would just install the package and import the component needed inside the file.

Comment: please read this https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/04/14/react-npm-how-to-publish-a-react-component-to-npm